# Are the I and J registers special in DCPU-16?

Tags: assembly, dcpu-16

DCPU-16 includes 8 general registers named `A, B, C, X, Y, Z, I` and `J`. It's a bit of a programmer "trope" to use `I` and `J` for loop counters. In DCPU-16, are `I` and `J` specialized  registers, that should only be used in loops - or do they all end up the same colour in the end?

Comment: As far as I know the only official docs are here: http://0x10c.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt . So not sure you can get an answer unless Notch himself visits this site :-) My guess would be that they are not "reserved" registers and that they all are general purpose.

Comment: The interpreter is 140 lines of C code, don't hesitate to have a look-see.  No, nothing special about those registers.

Comment: @HansPassant Where is this interpreter?

Comment: At github, follow the google link.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you refer to this one: https://github.com/swetland/dcpu16/blob/master/dcpu.c ? It's an unofficial implementation so I'd say it's not 100% guaranteed to run like the "real thing". But since it follows the spec and the spec does not say anything about special registers I agree it should be ok.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Everything points out to the DCPU-16's eight main registers being "general purpose": while they are 'intended' for a certain use, programmers can use them as they will. The x86 has a similar architecture for its general registers.

The only special purpose registers on DCPU-16 are SP, PC and O.

Edit: The DCPU 1.3 specification introduces a single instruction (MVI) that adds 1 to both I and J after executing, with the intention of being used as a fast memory copy. Notch has expressed disliking this, so it might be eventually dropped, but now I and J *are* a bit special.

Comment: The intention of the x86 registers is encoded in the instruction set-- if you use them as they were originally imagined to be used, instructions tend to fit in 1 byte. http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html has a full treatment

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure conventions will emerge but the instruction set is completely orthogonal with respect to the registers `A, B, C, X, Y, Z, I` and `J` so there is no difference between them inherent in the `DCPU-16`.